# Noisy conditional simulation

Tags: simulation, spatial, noise, kriging, conditional-random-field

A conditional random field $Z_C(x)$ is a random field whose realisations $z_C(x)$ always take the same values $z_C(x_a)$ at locations $x_a$. Realisations of $Z_C(x)$ can be produced as follows (Journel and Huijbregts, 1978):

\begin{equation}
 Z_C(x) = Z_U(x) + Z_K(x) - Z_S(x)
\end{equation}

where $Z_U(x)$ is the unconditional simulation of the random field, $Z_K(x)$ is the simple Krige of $z(x_a)$ and $Z_S(x)$ is the simple Krige of the values of $Z_u(x_a)$

My question concerns the case where the values $z_C(x_a)$ were subject to a measurement error $z_C(x_a) = z_{C,0}(x_a) + \epsilon(x_a)$ where $z_{C,0}(x_a)$ is the true value of the process at location $x_a$ and $\epsilon(x_a)$ is a randomly distributed noise term. It is desirable for this noise term to be accounted for in the conditional simulation so that the $Z_C(x_a) = z_{C,0}(x_a) + \epsilon(x_a)$.

Can you link me to any relevant literature on the subject? Can you discuss the best approach adopted in this case?

[1] A. G. Journel and C. J. Huijbregts. Mining Geostatistics. Academic Press, 1978